# Responsive CSS isn't working properly?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Here's the site: [Website](http://webfro.gs/south/tour/national_presence.html)

There are some navigation arrows I'm trying to hide in mobile view.

**Here's the HTML...**

```
<div id="nav_arrow">
     <a href="index.html"><img src="images/icons/arrow_left.png" width="60" height="44"></a>
</div>
```

**Here's the CSS...**

```
#nav_arrow { display: none; }
```

The media query appears to be typed out correctly. The style works when the phone (iPhone 5) is held vertically. But, when I hold it in a landscape view, the arrows show up. I'm trying to not have them display unless the site is pulled up in tablet view or larger?

Any ideas?

**Update 1**
This is the section of CSS where I have the media query...

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {     

#nav { display:none;}
#secondary-nav { display:none; }
#footer-social { float:left; }
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-next-horizontal { right:0; }
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-prev-horizontal { right: 43px;}
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item { width: 300px !important; }
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item-horizontal {margin-right: 20px;}              
#latest-projects .block, #latest-posts .block, .programs .block { width:295px; height:inherit; }
#latest-projects .stack, #latest-posts .stack, .programs .stack { width:295px; height:274px; }
#latest-projects .block img, #latest-posts .block img, .programs .block img { width:283px; height:262px; }
#latest-projects .block .mask, #latest-posts .block .mask, .programs .block .mask { width:283px; height:261px; }
.nav-projects .viewall { display:none;}
#clients .block { width:298px;}
#clients .block img { width:298px;}
#info-block ul li > div { height: 85px; width: 270px; }
#latest-projects .block iframe, #latest-posts .block iframe, .programs .block iframe { width:283px; height:262px; }
.fix-fish-menu select { display:block; }
#menu { float: none; }
#clients .columns { padding-bottom:20px; }
.ribbon-front { left: 1px; }
.ribbon-edge-topleft, .ribbon-edge-bottomleft { display:none; }
#footer-social li { margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 0px; }
#top-panel .columns { margin-bottom:20px;}      
#contacts-form input[type=text], #contacts-form input[type=password], #contacts-form input[type=email] { width:130px;}
#contacts-form textarea { width: 290px; }
#contact-info li { width:275px; }
#latest-posts .mejs-container {width:265px !important;}
#latest-posts .block .text { height: 200px;}
#latest-posts .block { width:295px; height:274px; }
#nav_arrow { display: none; }
.link-icon { background-position: top: 100px; right: 100px; bottom: 100px; left: 60px; }
```

The specific  tag is on the bottom. Second to last.

Comment: We'll need a little more information to properly help you.

Comment: Please add the actual responsive part of the CSS. All your telling us is that you are setting the nav_arrow to display:none, but not really giving us the context of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the right mediaquery?, have you tried the **orientation** property:

```
@media only screen  and (min-device-width : 320px)  and (max-device-width : 568px)  and (orientation : landscape) {}
```

or maybe **device-aspect-ratio** would be more accurate for iphone 5:

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) and (orientation : landscape) {}
```

Comment: That was the issue. Everything's a go! Much appreciated!

Comment: @JaredNewnam This won't solve it for screens that are bigger than the iPhone. Then you will be back to the same problem

Comment: this answer only answer part of the question. Media queries will work for iphone5 but NOT for tablet view or larger.

Answer (score 2):

`Screen` in media queries are defined as anything on an screen, so not print, or other similar medias. Your media query is saying that those styles will only be displayed on a screen, and the screen has to be less than 480 pixels.

Chances are that when you tilt your iPhone to landscape, it increases the pixels past 480. So then all of those styles in that block are not applied, and the iPhone renders the default styles of screens bigger than 480 pixels. There are a few ways to solve this.

You could increase the `max-width` pixel value. This might be the solution you will have to go to. You will just have to be careful picking a value

- You don't want it too low. If you only target iPhone for this value, then any phones with a bigger screen won't have those styles. So you'd be back to the same problem
- You don't want it too high, because you might end up accidentally targeting some smaller screen notebooks, and then you have destroyed a little part of your UI

Chris posted a [good article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) relating to this. He has a lot of media queries you could use to solve this. But that might get a little heavy with queries.

Unfortunately, there isn't a query made yet that only targets handheld devices

Answer (score 0):

The width of the iphone5 landscape is 568px, so change your media query to something like:
`@media only screen and (max-width: 568px)`.

Maybe use 768 as a breakpoint for tablets (portrait).